# Call ArcGIS Repair Geometry Function from Oracle 11.2

Tags: arcgis-server, oracle-dbms, validation, integration

Could anyone please point me to the right direction on how to call an ArcGIS Function (i.e. Repair Geometry) from PL/SQL? All information I found so far concerns the other way round.

This is needed because Oracle's validation criterias differ from the ones used by ArcGIS causing some geometries produced within Oracle not drawn by ArcGIS services (see http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/36047).

The geometries are stored directly in Oracle.

I thought about calling arcpy directly PL/SQL but couldn't find any examples for that.
Is there a way without using ArcSDE?

Any thoughts on this would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Finally my way to get an ArcGIS Function (i.e. Repair Geometry) repair the geometries is by querying the relevant data using an FME job, having the data checked by an FME shutdown python script which uses arcpy, then inserting data back to the source tables. This is due to an distributed and restrictive environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use GeoRaptor in SQLDeveloper to validate SDO geometry and the generate a SQL script to rectify those errors. GeoRaptor will provide the exact ORA error. You can also validate metadata through GeoRaptor and with bad metadata, ArcGIS can have issues drawing the feature.